# What are the different ways to rotate matrices in GLM?

Tags: c++, math, glm-math

This

```
glm::mat4 someMatrix;
// ...
someMatrix = glm::rotate(someMatrix, glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

seems a tad long winded, but it's all google is turning up. I'd like to get to know what alternatives and utility functions exist for this kind of thing. For example:

```
matrix.rotate(...)
matrix.rotateX(...)
matrix *= glm::rotationmatrix(...)
```

Comment: Isn't there any, like, documentation?

Comment: There is, from which I found the above, but I'm not satisfied. I'll just write my own code but I wanted to double check there isn't more and I thought others might want something similar.

Comment: There is no such mathematical thing that rotate a matrix. `glm::rotate` multiplies a rotation matrix with a newly created one, concatenating the two rotations together. There is also a documentation, and you can also freely make an utility function if you want to make things shorter.

Comment: Thanks, @plasmacel I'm aware of all of this. I'm after a common collection of utility functions that we can all use instead of making our own.